# Is there a way to adjust the icon size in the Eclipse workspace?

Tags: eclipse, parallels

I am running an Eclipse IDE via Parallels on a Retina MacBook Pro.

Parallels automatically configures the font sizes in Windows to deal with the Retina display resolution. So all that looks good.

The problem is that the icons in the workspace are still the same size and as such render so tiny it is almost impossible to see them.

I would like to be able to tell Eclipse to resize the icons (probably by x2 or x4). I don't care if they look blocky, only that I can see them.

Is such a thing possible?

To pre-empt the obvious answers:

- I need to use the IDE in windows (due to JNI libraries).
- Also restarting straight into Bootcamp won't solve the issue either unless I lower the resolution. Which defeats the purpose of the extra screen real estate.

Comment: A related issue in the eclipse DMS can be found at: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=421383 . Hopefully bigger icons will be available during 2014

Comment: maybe this can help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20718093/eclipse-interface-icons-very-small-on-high-resolution-screen-in-windows-8-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring to the [User Interface Guidelines](http://wiki.eclipse.org/User_Interface_Guidelines#Icon_Size_.26_Placement) of Eclipse 3.x this is not possible at the moment. The icons (Toolbar for example) have a maximal size of 16px.

> The majority of Eclipse style icons are designed within an area of 16 x 16 pixels. That is the final cut size of the image.

The icons can be found here:

```
<eclipse-root>/plugins/org.eclipse.ui_*.jar/icons/full
```

Comment: Cheers! I take it I can manually patch them then? (edit) actually rereading your comment looks like this is not the case, as I would need to resize the toolbar as well. :/

Comment: I wonder if it's possible? I'm in the same boat, using a proprietary IDE that's based on Eclipse.

Comment: Have you tried to replace the icons and dit it work (icons not cropped on toolbar)?