# Are there any usable Java IDEs for High-DPI computers?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, ide

I have a Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro that has a QHD display at 3200x1800 resolution. Basically, everything is crystal sharp except in some programs, the majority of which are Java-based.

Unfortunately, I have a lot of programming to do that I would prefer to do in Java, but I simply cannot work with the insanely blurry fonts and tiny images in IntelliJ, Eclipse, and Netbeans.

If there are any developers in the same boat that I am, what are you using for your Java projects?

EDIT: This is not a duplicate question because I'm not asking for a specific "fix" for Eclipse. I'm asking what developers are finding as a solution to a lack of compatibility with Java IDEs in general.

FINAL EDIT: IntelliJ has done it. Even for Windows, the soon to be released IDEA 14.1 supports HiDPI on both Mac and Windows (not sure for Linux). I'm impressed, and very happy to use the IDE.

Comment: Interesting, I was planning on buying the same. First I thought this should go on "programmers" website, but I was apparently wrong, so I guess you are on the right site after all. Note that all of the above should have configurable fonts, maybe try one of the Liberation fonts or similar open source fonts.

Comment: I have to unfortunately recommend against getting this notebook if you're a Java developer. Also, it's not just choosing the font, everything is out-of-whack in every Java IDE.

Visual Studio runs perfectly, though.

Comment: Weird, because especially Swing was created with variable screen widths in the first place. Support for different font sizes etc. was added way before Windows supported design that was decoupled from pixels. Maybe there are some OS variables set incorrectly that can be used by an application to determine screen capabilities? An X1 would be nice as well, but that also has a high-res screen, I wonder if it would have the same issues.

Comment: Related Eclipse specific links: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20718093/589259 and https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=421383

Comment: As of 2015, IntelliJ 14 has been great on HiDPI computers. For anyone who may see this thread late.