# Aptana Studio 3 high resolution small icons

Tags: icons, size, aptana, resolution

I am using aptana Studio 3 with a resolution of 3840 x 2160. Now the icons in Aptana Studio are very small. Is there a way to change the size of the icons in Aptana Studio?

Answer (score 1):

Since Aptana is really Eclipse, I found the solution here:
[Eclipse interface icons very small on high resolution screen in Windows 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20718093/eclipse-interface-icons-very-small-on-high-resolution-screen-in-windows-8-1)
The solution that worked for me referenced this resolved bug, which is found here:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=421383#c60

The only difference is naming the manifest file. Instead of: *eclipse.exe.manifest*, name it this: 
***AptanaStudio3.exe.manifest***

I will repeat what they said:

> 1) Tell Windows to ignore settings from within applications (which are
>   clearly wrong, since the UI is unusable) if a "manifest" file is
>   available. Open registry editor and create the following DWORD
>   registry key:   Enable Windows to prioritise external manifests by
>   creating and setting this registry key (use regedit.exe)
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SideBySide\PreferExternalManifest
>   (DWORD) to 1
>
> 2) Create a "manifest" file that tells Windows that
>   Evernote is not using high dpi UI: Create the file
>   AptanaStudio3.exe.manifest with the contents of the attachment to this
>   bug "Manifest file to fix this issue on high DPI displays" and place
>   it in the same folder as AptanaStudio3.exe.

Now here is what you put in the file, AptanaStudio3.exe.manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">

<description>eclipse</description>


<trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
  <security>
    <requestedPrivileges>
      <requestedExecutionLevel xmlns:ms_asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3"
        level="asInvoker"
        ms_asmv3:uiAccess="false">
      </requestedExecutionLevel>
    </requestedPrivileges>
  </security>
</trustInfo>

<asmv3:application>
  <asmv3:windowsSettings xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">
    <ms_windowsSettings:dpiAware xmlns:ms_windowsSettings="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">false</ms_windowsSettings:dpiAware>
  </asmv3:windowsSettings>
</asmv3:application>

</assembly>
```

I had to reboot my machine before it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I have enlarged all images with imagemagick in directory configurations on my linux to 32 px.

```
for im in (find -name \*.png -or -name \*.gif) do convert "$im" -resize 32x $im done
```

[image: editor screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue:

If your operating system supports it (Windows 10), you try the following:

Right click the application and select "Properties" > select "Compatibility" tab > check the check box "Override high DPI scaling behavior. Scaling performed by:" > select "System" from the drop-down.

If the "System" option does not work then try selecting "System (Enhanced)".

Hope this helps!