# Eclipse Icons are really small on high resolution screen

Tags: java, eclipse

As the title says, the icons in Eclipse are really small on my 2560x1600 laptop screen. I find that even turning down the resolution and plugging it into my 1080p monitor still results in the icons being tiny.

I found an answer that led to this site: https://github.com/davidglevy/eclipse-icon-enlarger but I have no idea how to use that. Could someone please help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's a more polished fork: https://github.com/PhantomYdn/eclipse-icon-enlarger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author posted [instructions for his tool here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23024828/1438038). Basically, you have to run it from the command line and need to specify the Eclipse base directory. The tool will then iterate over all directories in order to double the size of all icons.

Syntax for usage is:

```
java -jar eclipse-icon-enlarger.jar \
            -b <Your Eclipse base directoy> \
            -o <Desired output directory> \
            --resizeFactor <Factor for icon increase>
```

Comment: Sorry for the newbie question, but where would I get that .jar file from?

Comment: You can find a JAR file [here](https://github.com/imzcy/eclipse-icon-enlarger-binary/releases/download/0.0.0.1/enlarger.jar). It's name is different, but it's based on the same project.

Answer (score 2):

This has been fixed in the latest version of eclipse, [Eclipse Neon](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.6/platform.php):

> SWT now automatically scales images on high-DPI monitors on Windows
>   and Linux, similar to the Mac's Retina support on OS X. In the absence
>   of high-resolution images, SWT will auto-scale the available images to
>   ensure that SWT-based applications like Eclipse are scaled
>   proportionately to the resolution of the monitor.
>
> [image: new eclipse]
>
> For comparison, here's how it looked in Mars without high-DPI support:
>
> [image: old eclipse]

Answer (score 0):

Another way that I discovered is to modify your registry file.

1. Open **regedit** and go to **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SideBySide**
2. Add a new DWORD (32-bit) Value: PreferE‌​xternalManifest with a decimal value of 1
   [image]
3. Go to your eclipse folder and create a new file: **eclipse.exe.manifest** and add the following text to the file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">

  <description>eclipse</description>

  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel xmlns:ms_asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3" level="asInvoker" ms_asmv3:uiAccess="false">
        </requestedExecutionLevel>
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>

  <asmv3:application>
    <asmv3:windowsSettings xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">
      <ms_windowsSettings:dpiAware xmlns:ms_windowsSettings="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">false</ms_windowsSettings:dpiAware>
    </asmv3:windowsSettings>
  </asmv3:application>
</assembly>
```