# Eclipse icons are very small on high resolution screen - Windows 8.1, Lenovo Yoga Pro 2

Tags: eclipse, windows-8.1

I am trying to work with Eclipse on my laptop - 3200x1800 resolution.

A majority of the icons are practically invisible.

I found two discussions on this very topic:

[Eclipse interface icons very small on high resolution screen in Windows 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20718093/eclipse-interface-icons-very-small-on-high-resolution-screen-in-windows-8-1)

[Eclipse Icons are really small on high resolution screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32309024/eclipse-icons-are-really-small-on-high-resolution-screen)

Where it can be seen that this is an open issue in the eclipse bug system, yet to be fixed:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=382972

I tried the workarounds suggested in both discussions:

1. Using Windows XP compatibility mode didn't work for me since it was removed in Windows 8.1 eclipse version).
2. Setting a lower resolution results in an ugly result since my laptop is configured to work with high resolution for most applications.
3. The solution suggested here -

[Eclipse interface icons very small on high resolution screen in Windows 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20718093/eclipse-interface-icons-very-small-on-high-resolution-screen-in-windows-8-1/23024828#23024828)

seemed the most promising one. However, even when I observed there are new forks for this GitHub project, and tried the newest one -

https://github.com/PhantomYdn/eclipse-icon-enlarger

it failed for me: I managed to create the jar file as instructed and run it on my Eclipse, however the resulting eclipse.exe fails to run with a message: "The eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library".

By googling this one I found -

[Eclipse executable launcher error: Unable to locate companion shared library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070968/eclipse-executable-launcher-error-unable-to-locate-companion-shared-library)

which led me to a conclusion that the enlarger just didn't work correctly. Since I don't know Java yet, I'm a bit stuck now.

How do I proceed from here?

Alternatively, is there another solution for my problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am working through this issue myself. So far the best post I found is this:

https://jaxenter.com/netbeans/hidpi-with-eclipse-and-netbeans

It seems that there has been a resolution for this already. Bug 421383 – [Graphics] Scaling issues on high DPI displays

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=421383#c60.

Hope this helps!