# How to increase size of maximize,minimize,close buttons in Eclipse Mars

Tags: eclipse

How can I increase/decrease the size of maximize, minimize, close as well as other buttons in Eclipse mars IDE in Windows.

[image: screencap]

Answer (score 1):

Please use eclipse neon. This problem has been fixed in that release.

Note: scaling is controlled by zoom settings in OS display settings

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not related to IDE but your OS.Go through

[Eclipse interface icons very small on high resolution screen in Windows 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20718093/eclipse-interface-icons-very-small-on-high-resolution-screen-in-windows-8-1)

for solution

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on eclipse application icon, select **properties**, in compatibility tab you must select DPI check.

[image]