# Where does Anaconda Python install on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, pydev

I installed Anaconda for Python 2.7 on my Windows machine and wanted to add the Anaconda interpreter to PyDev, but quick googling couldn't find the default place where Anaconda installed, and searching SO didn't turn up anything useful, so.

Where does Anaconda 4.0 install on Windows 7?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

To find where Anaconda was installed I used the "where" command on the command line in Windows.

```
C:\>where anaconda
```

which for me returned:

> C:\Users\User-Name\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\Scripts\anaconda.exe

Which allowed me to find the Anaconda Python interpreter at

> C:\Users\User-Name\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\python.exe

to update PyDev

Comment: The `where` command is a nifty trick. My installation is at `C:\Users\User-Name\Anaconda3\Scripts\anaconda.exe`.

Comment: This doesn't work if Anaconda is not in your system path. Rusy's answer is more universal.

Comment: continuum can grow large.  Mine is 22 Gigabytes

Comment: If you use where in the Anaconda Prompt it ensures that the system path does have Anaconda and this solution will work. @fivef

Answer (score 55):

Open the Anaconda Prompt and type:

```
> where python
```

Comment: This is the answer that worked best for me. Somehow PyCharm could only find an installation in C:>users\<user>\venv, but that didn't work correctly. The one I found with `where python` in the Anaconda prompt did

Answer (score 41):

You can search for "Anaconda prompt" in installed programs and run it. 
When it opens, it shows the directory anaconda is working from. 
[image]

As you can see c:\programdata\anaconda2 is my installed directory.
*side note: programdata folder is hidden in windows so you'll have to enter its path in the folder explorer to access it.

Comment: For me, it just says `"(base) C:\Users[...]"`. u2gilles' answer should work for more users.

Comment: I did a clean and first time install of Anaconda 5.1 on Windows 10 Pro. I can't even start Anaconda prompt (Windows Search show 1 result for 'Anaconda prompt'): "'C:\Users\xxxx\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: I found my anaconda installation at ``"C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\"``. ``Program Data`` folder was hidden by default.

Answer (score 20):

`conda info` will display information about the current install, including the *active env location* which is what you want.

Here's my output:

```
(base) C:\Users\USERNAME>conda info

     active environment : base
    active env location : C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : C:\Users\USERNAME\.condarc
 populated config files :
          conda version : 4.8.2
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.7.6.final.0
       virtual packages : __cuda=10.2
       base environment : C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3  (read only)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\USERNAME\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\Users\USERNAME\.conda\envs
                          C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.8.2 requests/2.22.0 CPython/3.7.6 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.18362
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

If your shell/prompt complains that it cannot find the command, it likely means that you installed Anaconda without adding it to the PATH environment variable.

If that's the case find and open the **Anaconda Prompt** and do it from there (the Anaconda Prompt should be available in your Start Menu (Win) or Applications Menu (macos))

Alternatively reinstall Anaconda choosing to add it to the PATH or add the variable manually.

Answer (score 11):

If you installed as admin ( and meant for all users )

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\anaconda.exe
```

If you install as a normal user

```
C:\Users\User-Name\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\Scripts\anaconda.exe
```

Answer (score 6):

`where conda`

F:\Users\christos\Anaconda3\Library\bin\conda.bat

F:\Users\christos\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe

F:\Users\christos\Anaconda3\condabin\conda.bat

`F:\Users\christos\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe --version`

conda 4.6.11

this worked for me

Answer (score 5):

This one is easy. When you start the installation, Anaconda asks "Destination Folder" as below screenshot. If you are not sure where did default installation go, double click setup file and see what anaconda offers as a default location.
[image: Anaconda image]

Answer (score 3):

```
C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2
```

For me this was the default installation directory on Windows 7. Found it via [Rusy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45320307/1242521)

Answer (score 2):

With Anaconda prompt python is available, but on any other command window, python is an unknown program. Apparently Anaconda installation does not update the path for python executable.

Comment: updating the path is an option during the Anaconda installation. I think the default (and recommended option by Anaconda) is 'off'.

Answer (score 2):

Update May 2020, installed Anaconda 3 Individual Edition from https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual, chose 32-bit installer for Python 3.7, and installed with Default options.

[image]

Here is the directory where Anaconda was installed (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3). Note ProgramData is a hidden folder not visible via Windows File Explorer.
[image]

And launching Anaconda command prompt from Start Menu>>Anaconda3 gives below command shell

[image]

"**where anaconda**" command gives below output
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\anaconda.exe
and versions for anaconda, conda, python
[image]

Updated original question which was asked 3 years ago, and is relevant today as well in May 2020 as I had similar question/doubt when installing Anaconda recently.

Answer (score 2):

The given answers work *if* you're in a context where conda is in your PATH environment variable, e.g. if you set it up that way during installation, or if you're running the "Anaconda Prompt".

If that's not the case, e.g. if you're trying to locate conda for use in a script, you should be able to pick up its installation location by probing `HKCU\Software\Python` for available Python installations. For example:

```
>for /F "tokens=2,*" %a in ('reg query HKCU\Software\Python /f InstallPath /s /k /ve ^| findstr Default') do @echo %b
C:\Users\<username>\Miniconda3
C:\Users\<username>\Miniconda3
```

Answer (score -2):

cmd.exe /K C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat

Comment: This does not answer the question.