# Set a Default Interpreter and use NO virtualenv in PyCharm 2017

Tags: pycharm, anaconda

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04. I went to `File > Default Settings > Project Interpreter > add local` and browsed to my `anconda3/long/path/python3.6`. When I open a new project or file the anaconda interpreter is NOT chosen, and instead a virtual environment based on the systems default python3 interpreter is created in `/home/myname/venv` and is used. To change it I need to go into settings, search for "interpreter" and choose the anaconda3 I added earlier, but that's a hassle!

How can I get PyCharm to use the Anaconda3 interpreter by default and avoid having those annoying virtual environments poping up in my home folder every time I need to write a script?

Comment: In the pycharm settings you have to select the default interpreter. And it will be the default for any project you create.

Comment: @WilsonPena How is your suggestion different from what I described in my question?

Comment: I'm pointing out that this is how you do it. Maybe you didn't save the configuration or you are using the project's settings.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PyCharm: Anaconda installation is not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47624777/pycharm-anaconda-installation-is-not-found)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a bit convoluted. When clicking `File > New Project` you get a pop-up window where you set the project name, under the name there is a little text saying `Project Interpreter: Python 3.6`. Click on it and some options expand. The preset option is `New Virtual Environment` with the default system interpreter. The other, not set option, is `Existing Interpreter` which is the one you set in the Default Settings.