How to use Python's subprocess to run a 'conda list' command and pipe it to a text file
My objective is to use Python's subprocess module to run the following 'conda list>[fullPath_based_on_date]' command in the Anaconda prompt environment:
r'conda list>z:\backup\Anaconda\conda_list_2024-05-06_13-23-45.txt'

I have not been able to find a way to get subprocess to run that command in an Anaconda environment.
But I composed the Python script below hoping that someone will give me some hints about how to fix it, and where I can learn about what I did wrong.
Here is my Python script:
import os
import subprocess
from datetime import datetime as DTT

NL, TAB, NLT = '\n', '\t', '\n\t'# {NL}{TAB}{NLT}

DT_now_str = (f'''{(DTT.now()).strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M")}''')
DT_now_str_wSeconds = (f'''{(DTT.now()).strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")}''')
print(f'''{DT_now_str = }{NLT}'''  +
    f'''{DT_now_str_wSeconds = }''')

dst_fullPath_based_on_date = r'z:\backup\Anaconda' + os.sep + 'conda_list_' + DT_now_str_wSeconds + '.txt'
cmd_conda_list_piped2txt = r'conda list>' + dst_fullPath_based_on_date
print(f'''{NL}{cmd_conda_list_piped2txt = }''')

subprocess.run(cmd_conda_list_piped2txt)
print(f'''{NL}{exitcode = }''' +
    f'''{out = }''' +
    f'''{err = }''')

cmd_edit_conda_list = r"C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" + ' ' + dst_fullPath_based_on_date
print(f'''{NL}{cmd_edit_conda_list = }''')

subprocess.run(cmd_edit_conda_list)
print(f'''{NL}{exitcode = }''' +
    f'''{out = }''' +
    f'''{err = }''')

Any suggestions about how to get the subprocess module to run the 'conda list>[fullPath_based_on_date]' command in an Anaconda environment would be much appreciated.
Thank you,
Marc

In order to get that > interpreted as a file redirection character, rather than just another character in a parameter, you have to add shell=True to the subprocess call.

Thank you. Much appreciated. Since no one except you answered, I'm thinking maybe it's not possible and I should ask instead if someone knows how to do a similar script using PowerShell.

# runme.py

from datetime import datetime
import subprocess


datetime_str = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")
filename = f"{datetime_str}.txt"

with open(filename, "w") as f:
    subprocess.run(["conda", "list"], stdout=f)

print(f"{filename} written!")

Execute the script within the PowerShell Prompt or CMD.exe Prompt:
python .\runme.py

e.g.
(base) PS C:\Users\HP> python .\runme.py
2024-05-16_16-04-46.txt written!
(base) PS C:\Users\HP>


To execute a command and redirect its output to a file, just use subprocess.run. It has all the options.
with open(dst_fullPath_based_on_date, "w") as f:
    subprocess.run(["conda", "list"], stdout=f)

See subproces.run and subprocess.Popen documentation.

Thank you. That is part of the solution, but I cannot figure out how to get the subprocess module to run the 'conda list' command in the Anaconda Prompt environment instead of the standard Windows terminal environment.

how do you enter "anaconda prompt environment"?

On my machine the link to Anaconda prompt is a shortcut with this target:
%windir%\System32\cmd.exe "/K" %APPDATA%\..\Local\anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat %APPDATA%\..\Local\anaconda3

So I would propose to do:
import subprocess

# define 'shortcuts'
windir = r'C:\Windows'
anaconda_path = r'C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\anaconda3'  # put your username
env_to_activate = 'py39'  # env that you want to 'conda list'

# define command:
# from my Anaconda command prompt shortcut, the line below activate base environment
command = fr'{windir}\System32\cmd.exe "/K" {anaconda_path}\Scripts\activate.bat {anaconda_path}'
# if you need another env activated:
command = command + f'| conda activate {env_to_activate}'
command = command + '| conda list'  # pipe gives execution once previous command is done (ie conda activate)
command = command + '> conda_list.txt'  # write to this file

# now, run the above command:
subprocess.run(command)


There is no dir on my PC matching 'C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\anaconda3'. So I tried setting anaconda_path = r'C:\ProgramData\anaconda3'. The error msg retd was 'conda' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. Maybe it's my ignorance. I've never created an Anaconda envelope. Do I need to do something to create an envelope for this?

I you don't know where Anaconda is installed, you can get the In startup menu, start to type "Anaconda prompt", click and launch the Anaconda Prompt, then 'where anaconda' (see eg https://stackoverflow.com/a/37117572/5552507).
