# Changing font size of non 'plain text' and 'rich text' elements in Spyder interface

Tags: python, fonts, spyder

I'm new to Spyder, I have used the program several times but when I started it recently something seemed off. The font size of my file names and all the tabs are very big all of a sudden. In `Tools -> Preferences -> Appearance`, the font size of the 'plain text' and 'rich text' can be adjusted, but this doesn't affect the font size I try to alter.

Changing DPI settings also doesn't seem to help. Since I could not find anyone with the same question, I post it here. See attached screenshot, where I highlighted the text I want to make smaller.

Kind regards,

Billy

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue as you and it was solved by using Anaconda.

When you install Spyder via Anaconda, you can change the startup settings for Anaconda and they should propagate through to Spyder.

I found the answer by JarroVIGT ([Spyder interface icons very small on high resolution screen in Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35854289/spyder-interface-icons-very-small-on-high-resolution-screen-in-windows-10)) to be extremely helpful.

I tried both dpiawareness=0 and 1 and 1 worked for me.

Comment: After reinstalling (via anaconda), rebooting, and altering the dpiawarness the problem was solved. Thank you for the respons