# Spyder Tab Font Size Too Small

Tags: spyder

[The screenshot of my Spyder interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRhrz.png)
As you can see, although the font size of code and other texts are normal, the tab font size is so small that is almost unreadable.

Current Python Version: 3.10.9
Current Spyder Version: 5.4.1

- I tried to adjuct DPI and resolution setting, which doesn't change the tab font size
- I tried to find `qt.conf` but I failed as I reinstalled the whole Anaconda
- [here are some solutions for older versions of Spyder (or perhaps Anaconda)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65992777/changing-font-size-of-non-plain-text-and-rich-text-elements-in-spyder-interf)

Comment: This has nothing to do with Python.

Answer (score -1):

Right click the Spyder shortcut icon: 
-> Properties -> Compatibility -> Change high DPI settings 
-> High DPI scaling override -> Override high DPI scaling behavior. Scaling performed by: 
-> set "System"

Comment: I tried this suggestion, but it did not help