# Eclipse Calculates Scaling Factor Wrong

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt

[Rumor has it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43627026/3482793) that Eclipse supports high resolution screens with scaling active. Right now my Eclipse shows icons on my 3840 x 2160 monitor in 16 x 16 pixel, which is not usable.

I debugged the code and found that `DPIUtil.setDeviceZoom(int)` uses some fixed value for `nativeDeviceZoom`, and so always calculates 100 for `deviceZoom` (which is then used to scale images). The culprit seems to be the following line (#439):

```
deviceZoom = Math.max ((nativeDeviceZoom + 25) / 100 * 100, 100);
```

However by setting the `SWT_AUTOSCALE` property I can get around this, and then I'm able to see the Eclipse application with nicely auto-scaled icons.

The bigger problem is that when the scaling is 200, 150 or 100, `nativeDeviceZoom` is always 150, which means `deviceZoom` is always 100.

I have no idea what any of these methods are supposed to represent, and the calculation does not make any sense to me.

Still there must be something I can do to get it to work. What is it?

**Edit:** After restarting twice Eclipse and our application suddenly started to scale. Now, after restarting again, we are back to not scaling at all.

Comment: What platform is this? On macOS `Display` calls `setDeviceZoom` with the correct value for the `nativeDeviceZoom` argument.

Comment: @greg-449 Win10 with 64bit Eclipse.