# Eclipse Interface - make lines/area between windows thicker

Tags: eclipse, interface, icons, myeclipse

The lines dividing the windows in Eclipse are really thin, and when I need to resize a window, I have to struggle to point cursor exactly at the tiny area between the windows, and then click and drag to resize.

Any way to change the thickness of those lines?  Similar to [increasing icon size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20718093/eclipse-interface-icons-very-small-on-high-resolution-screen-in-windows-8-1) maybe?

[image: eclipse window divider lines]

Answer (score 0):

You need to be aiming to point to the space (or "sash") between the border lines, not on the border lines themselves. Note that the pointer should change when you are in the correct zone, in the sash.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but the problem is that this space between the lines is only 3-4 pixels wide.  Too small for me to aim.  I would like to bump it up to 10 pixels.

Comment: Ah, OK. Sorry, I misunderstood. I'm not aware of any way to increase the sash size. You could raise a bug on eclipse, perhaps, or try the eclipse forums: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/f/11/