# Eclipse runs javafx program with weird settings / weird screen / or misalignment

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

On two different laptops, when I run my javafx application on eclipse-- the background and objects that is loaded onto the screen is not where they are suppose to be positioned. For example, the ImageView background is supposed to be centered and fill the screen, but instead it appears immediately to the bottom-right. Only when I resize the screen (doesn't matter how big) but the background and objects automatically reposition themselves where they should be. I believe a possible cause is my eclipse settings, except they're all defaulted. I don't think it's something wrong with my code, because when I run the same code, the same program on a different desktop and on another laptop, everything appears as it should. I tried changing my screen resolution but that has no effect. I also tried changing using css to set and position my background but same results.

Has anyone had a similar problem or have any suggestions to fix this?

Please help! Thank you.

Comment: Are you running Windows 10? Since you mention resizing the screen temporarily fixes the problem possibly it's a [windows scaling problem](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ae/help/3025083/windows-scaling-issues-for-high-dpi-devices) maybe try the steps under "Workaround": "Adjust display settings, 
Windows 10, 

Select Display > Change the size of text, apps, and other items, and then adjust the slider for each monitor."

Comment: I do have a Windows 10 I tested different scalings but it didn't solve it but noticed it did change the program appearance. As it turns out, Eclipse doesn't handle high resolution screens very well. Because you mentioned the scaling problem, I did some research and I was able to find [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20718093/eclipse-interface-icons-very-small-on-high-resolution-screen-in-windows-8-1) , which one of the answers suggested overriding the high dpi scaling and it worked!

Thank you!!!